# converted PyQt5 .ui to .py shows "type object 'QPalette' has no attribute 'PlaceholderText'"

Tags: python, pyqt5

I just created an ui in QtDesigner, converted it to .py and imported to the main file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from design import Ui_MainWindow

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

tried to run:

```
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
  File "D:\downloads\design.py", line 53, in setupUi
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
AttributeError: type object 'QPalette' has no attribute 'PlaceholderText'
```

lines 53-54 in desgin.ui:

```
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 85, 255))
```

i'm not sure what went wrong here and how do i fix this.

Comment: what is the output of `python -c "from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR; print('PyQt5 version', PYQT_VERSION_STR)"` and `python -c "from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR; print('Qt version', QT_VERSION_STR)"`. Share the .ui file

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you are using a version `>=5.12`.

---

As per the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#placeholderText):

> This function was introduced in Qt 5.12.

Comment: the version is 5.15.2, looks like it's something about python - i managed to run the script via cmd, but it shows "Unknown property backgrpund-color" (yes, backgrpund) under every of my 12 push buttons.